# Get returned value from jar file using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have learned run a jar file using ActiveXObject Object in javascript.
Now, I need to get returned value from jar file. I can't use 'applet' because project requirement.

Here is simple coding...

```
function RunExe(){  
     w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
     w.run('C://WindowJar.jar');
     return true;
}
```

How can I get returned value from jar file not using 'applet'.

Thanks your advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only I think this could work is to print the 'returned value' from the jar with the function **System.out.println**.
So you can read this output in the javascript using the code below:

```
function RunExe(){  
     w = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");  
     var ex =w.Exec('C://WindowJar.jar');
     var ret = "";
     //read the output of the jar
     while (!ex.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
         ret += ex.StdOut.ReadLine();
     }
     //alert the output
     alert(ret)
     return true;
}
```

*This answer was based in this question*: [How can I run a local Windows Application and have the output be piped into the Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716284/how-can-i-run-a-local-windows-application-and-have-the-output-be-piped-into-the)