# Running application from web browser

Tags: java, npapi, browser-plugin, html5-filesystem

I would like to run application, for example Windows Calculator from a website. I consider using browser plugin, Java Web Start, something like agent or any other solution that would work on windows/linux, without much work to do.

Plugin way:
I saw that it could be done with **NPAPI** but it seems to be dead. I looked also at **FileSystemAPI** but it also seems to be dead. Is there any good API to do this?

Agent way:
I thought about Java agent that user will install and website would communicate with system through it.

Comment: Check out Javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716284/how-can-i-run-a-local-windows-application-and-have-the-output-be-piped-into-the it might be able to do something like this

Comment: Are you talking about running programs that the user would have installed already on their computer or running applications that would be hosted from your web page?

Comment: Do you mean run your own web app or applet, or are you literally talking about running the Windows Calculator on the user's hard disc when they click a button in a browser?

Comment: @JasonSperske @markspace - yes, that's what I'm talking about. Executing, for example, `C:\Windows\System32\calc.exe`. 
I'm familiar with web servers like Glassfish and Tomcat and deploying `war` web applications there. And, as far as I know, I can't trigger execution of user local program using Java on a server side.

Comment: There really isn't a method to accomplish this. Access to system resources (like applications that run locally) is the attack vector that a virus would use. Possibly by running an applet where you request system access from the user but here the browser would present a stern warning to not grant this access

Comment: @JasonSperske yes, I'm aware of that. But, for example, I can start Battlefield 3 from web browser - I just have to install Chrome plugin. As another example, when I log to corporate VPN networks, it launches desktop application, when I agree to start Java in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to do that by Java Web Start:

1) I've created Swing application, with source code as below. Based on http://java.dzone.com/articles/java-web-start-jnlp-hello tutorial.

Code below:

```
package com.gogowitczak;

import javax.jnlp.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    static BasicService basicService = null;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mkyong Jnlp UnOfficial Guide");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel();
        Container content = frame.getContentPane();
        content.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        String message = "Jnln Hello Word";

        label.setText(message);

        try {
            basicService = (BasicService)
                    ServiceManager.lookup("javax.jnlp.BasicService");
        } catch (UnavailableServiceException e) {
            System.err.println("Lookup failed: " + e);
        }

        JButton button = new JButton("http://www.mkyong.com");

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\calc.exe");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        button.addActionListener(listener);

        content.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.show();
    }
}
```

2) Besides of that, I created `MANIFEST.MF` file.

File is in `src\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF` path:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.gogowitczak.Main
Permissions: all-permissions
```

3) And, of course, `.jnlp` file, for Java Web Start.

File is in `src\JNLP-INF\APPLICATION.JNLP` path:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://localhost:8080/" href="Test.jnlp">
    <information>
        <title>Jnlp Test</title>
        <vendor>MyVendor</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/" />
        <description>Testing Testing</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <!-- <j2se version="1.7+" /> -->
        <j2se version="1.7*" java-vm-args="-Xmx32m" max-heap-size="32m" href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/>
        <jar href="jws.jar" />
    </resources>
    <application-desc main-class="com.gogowitczak.Main" />
</jnlp>
```

4) It should be possible to compile and run this project right from IDE you're using (IntelliJ is mine). Clicking on button should open new Windows Calculator window.

5) Create `.jar` from this project. In IntelliJ it's easy: File -> Project structure -> Artifacts -> '+' -> jar -> From modules with dependencies. Pick `com.gogowitczak.Main` as `Main Class`. Make sure that checkbox `Build on make` is selected.

6) Build project again. In `<project_path>\out\artifacts\<project_name>_jar` you should find `<project_name>.jar` file. For me it's `jws.jar`.

7) Now you need to create your own own certificate. It's required to sign `.jar` file. 
You can do it by running `keytool -genkey -keystore testKeys -alias jdc`. `keytool.exe` can be found in JDK installation directory, in `bin` folder. For me it's path `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\keytool.exe`. Remember password you set, other things are irrelevant right now. This method is based on [Oracle website](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signing.html)

8) Sign your `.jar` by executing `jarsigner jsw.jar jdc`. Most probably it will complain about lack of `.keystore` file in home directory. Move out `testKeys` file there, and change it's name to `.keystore` (If Windows would resufe to set a filename with dot at the beginning, you can always execute `move testKeys .keystore` for renaming it.

9) Now you have to put it on web server. Easiest way of doing that is setting up Tomcat. Download it from [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi), put our signed `.jar` file, together with copy of `APPLICATION.JNLP`, into `<tomcat_directory>\webapps\ROOT\` directory. Rename `APPLICATION.JNLP` to `Test.jnlp`

10) Now you can give it a try. Go to gttp://localhost:8080/Test.jnlp and see what happens. Every time browser wars you about danger, just keep agreeing to execute it anyway. If it fails, it's most probably caused by rejecting self-signed certificate. Open "Configure Java" menu and add `http://localhost:8080` entry to "Exceptions site list".

[image: Configure Java window]

11) Now go again to web browser and refresh page. This time executing java app should suceed, and after clicking a button, it should open Windows Calculator.

Don't hesitate to write a comment if I'm doing something wrong or if you have any questions. Hope it would help somebody. And remember about up-voting ;)

Answer (score -2):

May be you would Like to use an  [Applet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/)?

You may attach an applet to a web-page, it gets downloaded to the client site.They you will be able to preform operations.

Comment: Applets are going away; once Java 1.9 comes out, they won't be operational

Comment: @SheldonR. I Agree. So that is the reason for downvote ?

Comment: Yes, it was. I'm having to deal with applet replacement myself right now, which is why I said and voted the way I did...